# Equinox System bundle not exporting package

Tags: osgi, equinox

I am trying to embed Equinox into our current server side application.  Managed to start the osgi framework programatically.(via Spring)  The system bundle gets installed and started implicitly(I think).  However I noticed non of the system packages are exported!

```
osgi> ss
Framework is launched.
id      State       Bundle
0       STARTING    org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106

osgi> packages 0
No exported packages
```

As a result all plugins i try to start fails as they all Import package org.osgi.framework.

Anyone come across this?  Am I missing some config?

Thanks a lot!
*Climbing the Steep learning curve for OSGI*

My Code:

```
private void bootstrapOsgiFmk() {
    logger.info("Starting OSGI framework");
    FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
    config.put("osgi.console", "1234");
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE, "osgilogs/");
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, "true");
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA,"com.other.pkg");

    Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
    try {
      framework.start();
    } catch (BundleException e) {
      logger.error("Fail to start osgi framework.", e);
    }
    logger.info("OSGI started");
    context.registerService(IQuoteService.class.getName(), new SimpleQuote(),null);
}
```

Comment: How are you starting the framework? Have you done something with the value of the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages` property?

Comment: I have included my code which is called as part of a spring bean init.  I might have played with the config previously while trying to experiment.  Have an impression that fmk is stateful and restore at each restart.  I usually just delete the osgilogs dir.  Many thanks again for helping!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this code. It might be worth reporting a bug against Equinox, or you could try using Felix and checking the results there. BTW you're correct that the framework is stateful: you can even programmatically delete the storage directory if you don't want this property.

Comment: Incidentally if you do try with Felix, you will have to find an alternative for the console since Felix does not have a built-in console. You could install the Felix shell bundles for this.

Comment: thanks Neil appreciated.Reached a dead end here might give felix a try.  some thoughts that i had.possible spring classLoader conflicting with the osgi classloader?. no idea

Comment: Unsure. The list of system packages comes from a set of "profiles" embedded in the Equinox JAR, for example `J2SE-1.5.profile` defines the system packages for Java 5, etc. If Equinox can't load that resource then it might fail to export any system packages. Then again I would expect it to indicate some kind of error if that was the case.